# Why is this java code showing error?

Tags: java, netbeans

```
package mygridLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class MyGridLayout
{
    JFrame f;
    MyGridLayout()
            {
                f = new JFrame();

                JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
                JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
                JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
                JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
                JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
                JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
                JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
                JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
                JButton b9 = new JButton("9");

                f.add(b1);
                f.add(b2);
                f.add(b3);
                f.add(b4);
                f.add(b5);
                f.add(b6);
                f.add(b7);
                f.add(b8);
                f.add(b9);

                f.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

                f.setSize(300,300);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MyGridLayout();
    }
}
```

> Error: Could not find or load main class mygridlayout.MyGridLayout
>   C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on your Project in the project explorer
2. Click on properties
3. Click on Run
4. Make sure your Main Class is the one you want to be the entry point. (Make sure to use the fully qualified name i.e. mypackage.MyClass)
5. Click OK.
6. Clean an build your project
7. Run Project :)

If you just want to run the file, right click on the class from the package explorer, and click Run File, or (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>), or (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>)

Comment: I already did that.My main class is "mygridlayout.MyGridLayout".

Comment: try these steps Close netbeans and then delete this directory C:\Users\Your name here\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache

Start Netbeans again and let it read the project.

Test project. Run project. It should work fine.

Comment: Did that but still getting the same error but other programs are working fine.

Comment: try this last step Right click project > properties > run > browse for main class. or else rename the package name

Comment: this is the final step, Actuall, when you click the "Run" button on top of the netbeans window, it only run the application's main class . but this Sequence class is not the main class of the project most probably. for this case to run this class you have to right click on Sequence class editor and select Run or Run as menu. Then this class will be executed on separate console, I hope this will work ..